# Running knex queries synchronously

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have complex solution and I just need to run knex synchronously, is it possible?

I have scenario when `knex` query is run inside `Promise.mapSeries` for array with unknown number of elements. For each element some `knex query` is called, including `insert` query.

So, this insert could affect result for the next element of array.

```
var descriptionSplitByCommas = desc.split(",");
Promise.mapSeries(descriptionSplitByCommas, function (name) {
    // knex.select
    // knex.insert if select doesn't return results
});
```

This was not my initial code, so maybe even Promise.mapSeries should be removed. But I need each `descriptionSplitByCommas` array elements to be processed syncrhonously.

Otherwise often while processing next description in array I get SQL error, because of duplicate elements inserted for column with unique index. This would not happen if query would be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I am using native promises, so I do not have experience with mapSeries, therefore I cannot tell you what exactly is going on at current state.

However running several asynchronous commands in series instead of parallel is quite common. There is one important thing, you have to know - once you create Promise, you do not have control about how and when it will be resolved. So if you create 100 Promises, they all start resolving in parallel.
This is the reason, there is no method for native promises like Promise.series - it is not possible.

What are your options? If you need to "create promise at one place, but run it in another", then factory method is your friend:

```
const runPromiseLater = () => Promise.resolve(25);
// some code
const myRealPromise = runPromiseLater();
myRealPromise.then( //
```

Of course, you can create array with these methods, then is question - how to run it in series?

If you can use Node with support for async/await, then for cycle is good enough

```
async function runInSeries(array) {
   for (let i=0;i < array.length; i++){
     await array[i]();
     // or if you have only instructions in array then you get the value and then call some // await myMethod(array[i])
   }
}
```

If you cant use that, then async library is your friend: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

If you need to use the value from previous calls, you can use .waterfall